# Append data to files using TFS 2015 Tasks

Tags: scripting, tfs-2015

So I'm using TFS 2015 and its tasks to automate a build we have in our company.

I have a script that mostly reads some files and it's content and copies line by line to another file.

Imagine I have a file with:

**File.txt**

```
Hello world
It's a nice day
Bye
```

and I want to copy this line by line/append (not overwrite) to another file. But using one of the TFS tasks but I really cant figure out whic one to use or if it's even possible.

Can anyone help on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Generic 'Run PowerShell script' task?

Comment: ty but I was hoping for a more direct aproach if TFS had it. But you're it has to be with PowerShell script. thank you.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use default utilities [Batch script](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/utility/batch-script) task or [PowerShell](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/utility/powershell) task. Another option is using extensions in the Marketplace, like [Run Inline Powershell](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petergroenewegen.PeterGroenewegen-Xpirit-Vsts-Build-InlinePowershell).

Comment: yeah PowerShell or Batch I was trying to avoid cause I already have a script but it has stuff that I don't need like setting environment variables and etc. I'm gonna check your sugestion about the Run Inline Powershell. thank you so much.  :)